# Nginx forward from one domain to another domain with/without query params

Tags: redirect, nginx, forward, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am looking for help in nginx configuration while forwarding request to another domain.

- Service 1: https://firstserviceendpoint.com/app/products?param1=a&param2=b
- Service 2: https://secondServiceEndpoint.com/app/products?param1=a&param2=b

My requirement is redirect the call coming for service 1 to service 2 without changing the url.
**Browser should have service 1 url all the time**. Query params are dynamic so i need to forward all query params to service 2.

for eg:

- 'https://firstserviceendpoint.com/app/products' forward to  'https://secondServiceEndpoint.com/app/products'  without browser URL change.
- 'https://firstserviceendpoint.com/app/products?param1=a&param2=b' forward to  'https://secondServiceEndpoint.com/app/products?param1=a&param2=b'  without browser URL change.

i tried to put below configuration but it's not working

```
location /app/products/* {
      proxy_pass https://secondServiceEndpoint.com/app/products;
}
```

Thanks in Advance for the help.

Comment: remove the path `proxy_pass https://secondServiceEndpoint.com;`, paste the error.log

Comment: Make it `location /app/products/ {
      proxy_pass https://secondServiceEndpoint.com;
}` and it should work. You don't need to use a `*` in the location